# css alternate row colour bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Bootstrap framework v3.1.1. The table class `table table-striped`, colours the alternate rows `#f9f9f9`.

I am trying to use css to overwrite this rule with

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Using the above colours the non colourd rows by bootstrap however not the ones already coloured.

Comment: you are providing color to hover functionality, it will work on all `tr` when they get hovered. can you share some test HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:hover > td {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

This should work for every row